# FeatureVector, 'Not allowed to read resource /projects/xxx/feature-sets/kth'

Tags: python, feature-selection, mlrun

I got this error in case of read values from feature vector:

```
...
/python/test/fvvector/utils.py in read()
    115             features = ["xion/ad02.score", "xxx/kth.*"]
    116             vector = fs.FeatureVector("uc004-vector",features=features)
    117             vector.save()
--> 118             resp = fstore.get_offline_features("uc004-vector")

Exception: 'Not allowed to read resource /projects/xxx/feature-sets/kth'
```

When I used this code:

```
import mlrun
import mlrun.feature_store as fs

...
features = ["xion/ad02.score", "xxx/kth.*"]
vector = fs.FeatureVector("uc004-vector",features=features)
vector.save()
resp = fstore.get_offline_features("uc004-vector")
...
```

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: Are you sure that is the **whole** message?

Comment: The issue is with access rights but I do not know, how to change these rights.

Comment: Well, going by the message, the issue is with a local file or directory named `/projects/xxx/feature-sets/kth`.  Do you have permissions to access that file or directory?  Do you own it, or does some other user own it?

Comment: I have permission to the directory, but it is not enough :(. Do you know, how to set permission in MLRun/v3io?

Comment: I don't even know what MLRun/v3io **is**.

Comment: MLRun = framework for mlops with featurestore

Comment: @XiongChan I think, whole issue is about setting of relevant privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that you do not have enough privilegies in project 'xxx'. You have to add your account e.g. in my case account name 'jist' to the project 'xxx'.

You have to:

1. Choose the project, in your case 'xxx' (point 1. in picture)
2. Choose menu 'Project settings', folder 'Members' (points 2. and 3. in picture)
3. You need to '+ Invite new members' (in my case account 'jist') to the project and choose relevant privileges (point 4. and 5. in picture)

[image]

BTW: It is enough to add role 'Viewer', if you need to only read data from FeatureSet (and use it in Feature Vector). Full description of roles see [link](https://www.iguazio.com/docs/latest-release/users-and-security/security/#project-members)